# plus number per second with setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want my `sHand` to add 6 per second but it works only once, If I try to do something like this: `this.sHand++` it works fine and adds 1 degrees per second but I want 6 instead of 1 any solutions?

```js
  data:{
    sHand: 30
  },
  computed:{
    style(){
        return { transform: 'rotate(' + this.sHand + 'deg)'}
    }
  },
  created(){
    setInterval(() => {
        this.sHand + 6  // not working :/
    },1000)
  }
```

```html
    <div :style="style" class="secondhand"></div>
```

Comment: you have typo problem . U missed assign it

Comment: 1. Is that code snippet an object like the following `{data: {}, computed: {}...}`? 2. do you want to increment by 6 every second the property `data.sHand`?

Comment: @Ele It's VueJS.

Comment: @marco-a this is vue, my goodness, I'm lost xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the assignment.

`this.sHand++` actually means:

`this.sHand = this.sHand + 1`

So, it's incrementing and the assigning.

```
this.sHand += 6
```

will do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **assign** the value back to `this.sHand`:

```
this.sHand = this.sHand + 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value to `this.sHand` after incrementing it.

```
created(){
    setInterval(() => {
        this.sHand = this.sHand + 6
        // or this.sHand += 6
    },1000)
  }
```